# Collect tweets of a user handle using specific keywords and dates?

Tags: python, twitter, data-analysis, social-media

I want to fetch some tweets of a specific user handle with a specific keyword and dates?

These are the parameters.

```
screen_name = "DelhiPolice" 
startDate = datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0)
endDate = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0)
query = "corner" # The search term we want to find
language = "en"
```

The below code prints the tweets text with specific keyword and particular startdate and enddate.

```
results = api.search(q=query, lang=language, since = startDate , until= endDate )
# for each through all tweets pulled
for tweet in results:
   # printing the text stored inside the tweet object
   print (tweet.user.screen_name,"Tweeted:",tweet.text)
```

This code prints all the tweets text of all the user handles matching keyword and date but I only want tweets of specific mentioned user handle.

Also, `api.search` is only pulling a maximum of 100 tweets. I want to pull more. What should I do in that case?

I'm new in this field. Please help.

Comment: Have you checked this endpoint https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline ?

Comment: You could either use the `screen_name` value as part of the query (eg. `query = "corner from:" + screen_name`), or you could look at the user's timeline instead of using search.